# raw_id_fields and ManyToMany in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-orm

I want to use raw_id_fields on a ManyToMany relationship in the admin, and I want each related object to show up on its own row (as opposed to a comma-separated list in a single field, which is the default behavior). Following examples spotted in the wild, it seems like I should be able to do this:

```
# models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    follows = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='followees')

# admin.py
class FollowersInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Profile
    raw_id_fields = ('follows',)
    extra = 1

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('user__first_name','user__last_name','user__username',)
    inlines = (FollowersInline,)

admin.site.register(Profile,ProfileAdmin)
```

But that generates the error:

```
<class 'bucket.models.Profile'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'bucket.models.Profile'>
```

I'm not clear what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are setting the wrong model for your `InlineAdmin`
as the model for followers you are defining is `User` and not `Profile`.

Looking at the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models) I'd say you should try:

```
class FollowersInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Profile.follows.through
```

and

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    exclude = ('follows',)
    inlines = (FollowersInline,)
```

Comment: Thanks Arie, but that gives me:

'FollowersInline.raw_id_fields' refers to field 'follows' that is missing from model 'Profile_follows'.

follows exists as a field on Profile.

Comment: Mmmh, probably I am not completely understanding what you are trying to do: You are trying to relate `Followers` and `Profiles`, right? From my understanding you should be able to ommit `raw_id_fields = ('follows',)` on your `InlineAdmin`. Then you can use the inline forms to associate `Followers` (`User`) to `Profiles`.

Comment: Followers is not a separate model - 'follows' is the name of an m2m field on the Profile model. I can omit follows from ProfileAdmin, but when I add inlines = (FollowersInline,) to ProfileAdmin, I get one of the two errors described above, depending on whether I use 'model=Profile' or 'model=Profile.follows.through'. Thanks.

Comment: Well, i meant Followers a.k.a. Users (as that is the model `follows` relates to). From my understanding ommitting the raw_id field *and* using Profile.follows.through should work. But as it doesn't I can only hope someone comes up with a better idea. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In inline for m2m connection you should use `through` table and for `raw_id_fields` setting you should use fields from that `through` table - inside this table fields can be name different as you expect.

You need goes to sqlite3/psql etc. terminal to see `through` table schema and use propper field for `raw_id_fields`.

```py
class FollowersInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Profile.follows.through
    # raw_id_fields = ("follows",) <- wrong
    raw_id_fields = ("user",) # <- probably right, because your m2m relation with `User` table and django use name of that table to name field in `through` model
```